# Странное поведение jquery ajax - "знак вопроса"

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Суть такова: есть чат в нем отправка сообщения посредством ajax jquery. Если отправлять в тексте один "знак вопроса", т.е. "?", то в php получается значение, например, "jQuery1102026802631956525147_1390501797156", если со знаком вопроса отправить какой-то символ, то в php получается именно тот самый текст, который был отправлен. Сама функция ниже, уже голову сломал в чем проблема:

```
function ajax_message_window_send_message(text, zadanie_id, type) 
{
    alert(unescape(text)) ;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_script/messages_window.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'action=send&id=' + zadanie_id + '&text=' + text + '&type=' + type,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            show('btn_send_message');
            hide('loader_mesage');
            $('.infrsend').html(data.text);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @wstudiokiwi, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запрос сделать вот так:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_script/messages_window.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        action: 'send',
        id: zadanie_id,
        text: text,
        type: type
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        show('btn_send_message');
        hide('loader_mesage');
        $('.infrsend').html(data.text);
    }
});
```

Когда Вы параметры указываете так как в Вашем коде, jQuery считает что у Вас JSONP запрос, и вместо ? ставит функцию callback.

Comment: спасибо за помощь